# Android GridView Speed Up Scrolling

Tags: android, performance, gridview, scroll

I have a GridView where each cell contains a number with a particular text color and a particular background image (see image).

The getView() method that generates it is below. **Can the scrolling speed be improved?**

[image]

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int row = getRow(position);
    int col = getCol(position);

       TextView view;
       if (convertView == null) {
           view = new TextView(context, null);
           view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

           if (answer[row][col] == ROW_MARKER) {
               view.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
               view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblue);
           }
           else {
               view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                       view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblack);
            }
        }               
        else 
           view = (TextView) convertView;   

        if (answer[row][col] == ROW_MARKER) {
               view.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
               view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblue);
               view.setText(Integer.toString(getRow(position) + 1));
        }
        else {
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblack);
            view.setText(Character.toString(answer[row][col]));
        }
        return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Changing my code here. I think your code above is just a bit redundant but otherwise ok.**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int row = getRow(position);
        int col = getCol(position);

TextView view;
if (convertView == null) {
    view=new TextView(context,null);
    view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
} else {
   view=(TextView)convertView;
} 


if (answer[row][col] == ROW_MARKER) {
            view.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblue);
            view.setText(Integer.toString(getRow(position) + 1));
 } else {
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_whiteonblack);
            view.setText(Character.toString(answer[row][col]));
 }

return view;
}
```

Comment: Would caching of the images speed things up at all (and if so, how would that work) ?

Comment: Not sure if that's your problem, unless those drawables are large or something. Can you describe the scrolling issue you are seeing a bit more? Do you have the Gridview in a Scrollview? What is the slowness and is it on a device or emulator, etc.

Comment: The images are quite small, but there can be a LOT of them, up to 2000 individual cells at the max. Scrolling only gets bad when the grid is populated with a large number of cells (no, there's no scrollview), and I am testing on a device. Is that slowness an inevitability when dealing with that many views?

Comment: If you only have 11 columns and 5 rows, then that's only 55 cells on screen at a time. So you should be ok. What is the performance of getCol() and getRow() like?

Comment: The picture I used was only a sample, the user can customize up to 2000 cells. getRow and getCol are a quick calculation, wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: But you don't have 2000 cells on the screen all at once do you? How many are on the screen at once? That is going to be a limiting factor I think.

Comment: Somewhere around 1000 max on the screen at a time, depending on the device size

Comment: can the images be cached to speed things up (if so, how does that work)!?

Comment: 1000 cells on the screen is probably the issue, but you can cache the backgrounds, I think something like: Drawable d1=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever); //or maybe need a call to getIdentifier()?// So just keep that drawable as a class variable. It may improve performance a bit.